# auto reference in c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, reference, auto

This code give me strange debug info in visual studio 2015

```
int main() {
    const int i = 42;
    auto j = i; const auto &k = i; auto *p = &i;
    const auto j2 = i, &k2 = i;
}
```

The resulting types were:

```
&k  = const int &
&k2 = const int *
```

I think those should both be `const int &`.

*Question is, why is my Visual Studio Debugger saying  `&k` and `&k2` are of different type?*

Comment: And the question is ... ? :)

Comment: Question is, why &k and &k2 are different type?

Comment: How do you know that &k and &k2 are of different types?

Comment: Upvoted on the grounds that I struggled to get my answer correct. I like to think that this question has depth. And is well-witten.

Comment: @cpplearner Visual studio debugging

Comment: @jakjaki How did you debug?

Answer (score 1):

`k` and `k2` are both `const int&` types.

---

Here is the full type list. Note that top-level `const` is discarded for `auto` type deduction.

```
int main()
{
    const int i = 42;
    auto j = i; // i is an int (const is top-level)
    const auto &k = i; // k is a const int&
    auto *p = &i; // p is a const int* (const persists as not top-level).
    const auto j2 = i, &k2 = i; // j2 is a const int, k2 is a const int&
}
```

Finally, if you had written

```
auto q = &k2;
```

then the type of `q` is a `const int*`, since the `const` is not top-level so is not discarded but `auto` type deduction. This recovers the debug info you observe.

`j2` and `k2` look dissimilar but really that's due to how declarations work with the comma, cf. The confusion can be unpicked by writing

`const int j2 = i, &k2 = i;`

You can always find out for sure using the C++11 standard library function `is_same`:
e.g.

`bool am_I_the_same = std::is_same<decltype(k2), const int&)::value`

Where `decltype` recovers the *type* of its argument.

Reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same

Comment: Thanks. The problem is, i don't understand why &k is ( const int & Reference ) BUT &k2 is ( const int * Pointer ) ? Shouldn't both be const int & ?

Comment: Do you trying to say that is because of debug environment? Why not &k ? j2 and k2 look dissimilar !? how declarations work with the comma !? I also Test with the is same as you said, it is true, but don't understand ... . Please review your answer! Thanks

Comment: No it is *nothing* to do with the debug environment. I prove why `q` is a `const int*`. As for the comma, it means that `j2` and `&k2` (read & as denoting a reference here) are the same `const auto` type.